# C++ Breaking up a string using multiple delimiters

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split a string into words by multiple delimiters in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters-in-c)

I'm currently trying to read a file where each line has a variation of tabs and spaces separating key attributes that need to be inserted into a binary tree.

My question is: How do I split a line up using multiple delimiters using only the STL? I've been trying to wrap my head around this for the good part of the day to no avail.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are many existing questions on this, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505965/fast-string-splitting-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c There are also pure STL solutions.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

```
vector<string> bits;
size_t pos = 0;
size_t newpos;
while(pos != string::npos) {
    newpos = str.find_first_of(" \t", pos);
    bits.push_back(str.substr(pos, newpos-pos));
    if(pos != string::npos)
        pos++;
}
```

Comment: what if the first character is one of these? Maybe start `pos` at -1, or do an initial search outside of the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Using `string::find_first_of()` [[1]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/):

```
int main ()
{
  string str("Replace the vowels in this sentence by asterisks.");
  size_t found;

  found = str.find_first_of("aeiou");
  while (found != string::npos) {
    str[found]='*';
    found=str.find_first_of("aeiou", found + 1);
  }

  cout << str << endl;

  return 0;
}
```