# c++ boost::iterator_range<iter> string_view error

Tags: c++, boost, string-view

I am trying to split a string the fastest way  possible in C++. I am getting an error here:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

using namespace std;
size_t const N = 10000000;
template<typename C>
void test_strpbrk(string const& s, char const* delims, C& ret)
{
    C output;

    char const* p = s.c_str();
    char const* q = strpbrk(p + 1, delims);
    for (; q != NULL; q = strpbrk(p, delims))
    {
        output.push_back(typename C::value_type(p, q));
        p = q + 1;
    }

    output.swap(ret);
}

int main()
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    typedef boost::iterator_range<iter> string_view;

    vector<string_view> vsv;
    test_custom(text, delims, vsv);
}
```

The Visual Studio says: `cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>'`

Can you please help me, should I enable any option in visual studio for this to work?

Comment: note: there is a `std::string_view` in the works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to convert a `char const*` to a `std::string::const_iterator`, e.g., when passing arguments to functions creating a range: although `std::string::const_iterator` may be a `typedef` for `char const*` there is no requirement that this is the case. I don't think your code give enough context to pin-point the exact problem, though. You might want to look for locations where you pass a string literal or take the address of a section of a `std::string` (i.e. something along the lines of `&str[index]` or `&*it`).

Based on you edit, what I suspected above actually got confirmed! You'll need to translate the `char const*`s your are playing with back to `std::string::const_iterator`s, e.g., by adding suitable offsets:

```
typename C::value_type(s.begin() + (p - s.c_str()), s.begin() + (q - s.c_str()))
```

Comment: Please see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505965/fast-string-splitting-with-multiple-delimiters

Comment: @SkyRipper: why? The referenced question and answers seem unrelated to your problem! _You_ should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), though! ... and the update to the article you just made **exactly** confirms what I have guessed: you try to constructor a `std::string::cont_iterator` from a `char const*`!

Comment: I did what you told me

Comment: @SkyRipper: You seem behind the time, though: I already updated the answer with the solution (although I'm not in a position to compile it easily to verify that I didn't make a typo; conceptually it will work, though).

Comment: how to use the typename please?

Comment: @SkyRipper: You replace the obvious expression where you are currently using it, i.e., it is the argument to `output.push_back(...)` in your updated code (don't expect others to write all your code).

Comment: Thanks for everything!